# Passing URL Encoded URLs as Parameters to Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a bit of a strange problem. I have a controller that is supposed to receive a URL as one of the parameters. I am encoding the URL, and trying to call the controller as such:

http://www.mysite.com/dowork/1/http%3a%2f%2fwww.otherurl.com

However, I am getting the error

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

What gives? Any way to handle this WITHOUT disabling validation?

Comment: Show how you are getting the value in your controller

Comment: It's simply one of the parameters of the Controller. I am letting the Routing Module do the rest.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if I use traditional query strings I don't have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is .NET 4.0, you can edit this configuration setting:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

If you don't wish to edit this, you can additionally encode your incoming url - use custom encoding (like replacing dangerous characters) or use base64 encoding or omit protocol part if possible before sending to controller (drop http://, if https:// is possible also, you need to think how to pass that).

Answer (score 0):

IF you pass it as a query string parameter (?path=....) you avoid the problem, the characters are only illegal as part of a path.

If you insist on passing the data as part of the path you will need to encode differently, like convert the string into a range of hexadecimal values or similar.